# Cross-platform MIDI input/output

Tags: cross-platform, midi

I want to take MIDI input from a device (like a keyboard), change some parameters (f. e. add a pitch bend) and send the resulting MIDI output to a device (like a software synthesizer).

I’d like to have a open-source, cross-platform (Windows, Mac OS, Linux) solution in C/C++ or Java that makes it easy to

- list and select MIDI input/output devices
- send and receive messages to/from these devices

I don’t necessarily need functions that compose the messages (like a pitch bend function that returns `0xE16000` for a semitone up pitch bend on channel 1), I’d be able to do that myself.

Looking for libraries I found [RtMidi](https://github.com/thestk/rtmidi), [PortMidi](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/), and the [Java MIDI package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html) but I’m not sure whether they fit my needs and whether there is an easier solution.

Which one would you recommend? Why? Are there other, maybe better possibilities?

Comment: Did you ever find out a suitable framework to use? If yes, could you write up an answer?

Comment: This was for a hobby project I didn’t pursue for long. I never really looked at the Java package and I’m not sure about PortMidi either. RtMidi seems to be able do the things listed above but I didn’t try compiling for Windows or Mac OS.

Comment: I've taken a look at RtMidi and it does seem to do the trick. I can create virtual midi devices and send midi to and from it. I haven't tried it cross-platform though, but it should work.